# AVPlayer current time is not working

Tags: iphone, uislider, avplayer

OK. AvPlayer is working great with streaming audio. In my app I have UISlider that shows current seconds of the playing song. Now I'm trying to make audio seek with UISlider.

Here is the code

```
-(IBAction)slide{
Float64 curSec = mySlider.value;
int32_t tScale = 600;
CMTime mySec = CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(curSec, tScale); 
player.currentTime = mySec;     <- error is here

NSLog(@"%f",mySlider.value);
}
```

The error is "Setter method is needed to assign to object using property assignment syntax"
In .h file I have AVPlayer *player; and @property(nonatomic, retain)AVPlayer *player. Also in .m I have @synthesize player;
So what is wrong? THANK YOU!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVPlayer_Class/Reference/Reference.html), it seems to me that you have to use `seekToTime:` method instead of setting time directly to the `currentTime` property.

Answer (score 1):

```
float second = 30.0;
CMTime time = CMTimeMake(second, 1);
[player seekToTime:time];
```